# Aggregating relationship properties on a path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to to get the SUM of the weights on each path my MATCH finds.  Query is below:

```
START n=node(10200) 
MATCH p=(n)-[r*1..5]->(m:Facility) 
WITH REDUCE(weights=0, rel IN r : weights + rel.weight) AS weight_sum 
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE 1=length(filter(m in nodes(p) : m=n))) 
RETURN p AS paths, length(p) AS pc,  
(weight_sum / (length(p) * (length(p) / 2))) AS sp;
```

Every time I run it, I'm getting...

```
Unknown identifier `p`
```

If I remove my WITH line (and the weight_sum RETURN value), the query knows what 'p' is and executes just fine.  Is there a problem with my query that the value of 'p' is being lost?  Is there a better alternative to get the SUM of these relationship properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pipe "p" to the next part of the query via the WITH:

```
START n=node(10200) 
MATCH p=(n)-[r*1..5]->(m:Facility) 
WITH REDUCE(weights=0, rel IN r : weights + rel.weight) AS weight_sum, p
WHERE ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE 1=length(filter(m in nodes(p) : m=n))) 
RETURN p AS paths, length(p) AS pc,  
(weight_sum / (length(p) * (length(p) / 2))) AS sp;
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Is there a reason why I have to do that with p but not with n, r or m?

Comment: r isn't being used after the WITH so no need to pass that on. m and n are actually redefined post the WITH so they're not really passed on from the earlier part of your query. You are just using p and weight_sum so those are sufficient